# Baby Rudin Definition 2.18 (i) : Bounded set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to self study Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* and I have been stuck on the definition of bounded sets stated in the book:

> $E$ is *bounded* if there is a real number $M$ and a point $q \in X$ such that $d(p,q) <M$ for all $p\in E$.

Why does Rudin say $q \in X$  ? What is the issue with the following definition :

> $E$ is *bounded* if there is a real number $M$ such that $d(p,q) <M$ for all $p\in E$ and $q\in E$.

If the second definition is wrong, can you give a counterexample ?

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to prove one, given the other? In one direction at least, it is not so hard. If you type your proof attempt above, we can check it.

Comment: Is the empty set bounded?

Comment: Both the definitions are equivalent. Probably Rudin uses first definition more in his further treatment.

Comment: if you think for example at the spherical shell centered in $x_0$, it is marginally better to fix a point $x_0$ and show that $|x-x_0|<M$ rather than taking two points and applying the triangle inequality w.r.t. $x_0$: $|x-y|<|x-x_0|+|x_0-y|<M+M...$

Comment: The second definition is the correct one. In the first one, the empty space is not bounded.

Comment: @Mason why isn’t the empty space vacuously bounded in both definitions?

Comment: @CSquared Take $X = E = \emptyset$. Then there does not exist any $q \in X$, so $\emptyset$ is unbounded according to definition 1, although $\emptyset$ becomes bounded when $X$ is non empty.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to "enclose" $E$ with a ball, that is, we must have 1) radius and 2) centre of the ball that "encloses" $E$.

With that in view, $E$ is bounded if $E$ can be "enclosed" in a ball.

That is, $E$ is bounded if there exists $q\in X$ (centre) and a positive no. $r>0$ (radius) such that:

$E\subset B_X(q,r)=\{t\in X: d(t,q)\lt r\}$

That is for every $p\in E$, we have $d(p,q)\lt r$.

What is wrong with the second definition?: Nothing!
Note that second definition implies the definition just stated above.

Comment: Thanks! It's clearer now. But I just have one more doubt. Does this also imply the same thing :  $E$ is *bounded* if there is a real number $M$ and a point $q \in E$ such that $d(p,q) <M$ for all $p\in E$.

Comment: I want to know why should $q \in X$ . Doesn't $q \in E$ do the trick ?

Comment: @PrassannaNandJha: If you replace "there is a real number $M$" by "there is a positive no. M" then yes that also works. Why? because $q\in E\subset X$ essentially means $q\in X$.

Comment: And why do we need to replace "there is a real number M" by "there is a positive no. M" ? We know $d(p,q) >0$ always. So,$ M$ will obviously be greater than $0$. Also, why should we do this now ? When $q \in X$, even then M is oviously positive .

Comment: @PrassannaNandJha: Good. If that is clear, then I have no complaints.

Comment: @PrassannaNandJha it is Ok to use $M\in \mathbb{R}$, but your definition in the  comments is good only if $E\ne\emptyset$, which is $\emptyset$ is bounded but does not satisfy your definition.

Comment: @Momo, I don’t think it really matters whether E is empty or not. If E is empty then vacuously it is bounded for any $M\gt 0$. Please correct me if I’m wrong. :)

Comment: @Koro I'm talking specifically about OP's the alternative definition " $E$ is bounded if there is a real number $M$ and a point $q\in E$ such that $d(p,q)<M$ for all $p\in E$ " which does not hold for empty set (because $\exists q\in E$ is false).

Comment: Yeah right! I get it. Thanks